# Use elasticsearch_async with tornado

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, asynchronous, tornado

I am trying to use elasticsearch_async ([repo](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py-async)) with tornado 6.0.3.

From what I understood going through the code, if I use `AsyncElasticSearch` and pass the current tornado `ioloop`, it will work. Can someone confirm or point to an example?

My second question is - I see `AsyncElasticSearch` uses `AIOHttpConnection` ([code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py-async/blob/master/elasticsearch_async/transport.py#L15)) internally as the default `connection_class`. Do I need to create a new `connection_class` adapter to pass to the `connection_class` which uses tornado's `AsyncHttpClient` or will the tornado work seamlessly with `AIOHttpConnection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understood going through the code, if I use AsyncElasticSearch and pass the current tornado ioloop, it will work. Can someone confirm or point to an example?

AsyncElasticSearch wants an `asyncio` event loop, not a Tornado IOLoop. But in Tornado 6 the Tornado IOLoop is just a wrapper around the asyncio event loop, so if you just ignore all of this and use the defaults everything should just work.

> Do I need to create a new connection_class adapter to pass to the connection_class which uses tornado's AsyncHttpClient or will the tornado work seamlessly with AIOHttpConnection?

No. Just let AsyncElasticSearch use aiohttp even if other parts of your application are using AsyncHTTPClient. It should all just work together (although I haven't actually tried this combination).

Comment: Thanks Ben for the response. I actually tried this a week back by using the default event loop that tornado uses internally and wrote an adapter class to handle Elastic search connections through native AsyncHTTPClient and it is working flawlessly. I haven't tried AIOHttpConnection thought but as per your explanation, it seems it will work as well.